# window.fetch() downloads the file to the client's file system

Tags: fetch-api

Calling `fetch(url, {method: 'GET'})` causes Chrome 111 on Windows 10 to *download* the file to the file system on at least one test device, which seems, y'know, entirely insane.

What could cause `fetch()` to try to save a file to the drive? Is there something I can do client-side or server-side to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: What's the content type of the response?  Can you provide more details on how to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was a Chrome extension called IDM Integration Module, which connected to a natively installed download manager and for whatever reason hijacked `fetch` requests instead of just normal downloads.